# A generalisation of the rearrangement inequality?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a_i\ge b_i$, $c_i\ge d_i$ ($i=1,2$) be real numbers. Let $a=\min(a_1,a_2)$, $A=\max(a_1,a_2)$, and similarly define $b,B$, $c,C$ and $d,D$. Does one have $$(a-b)(c-d)+(A-B)(C-D)\ge (a_1-b_1)(c_1-d_1)+(a_2-b_2)(c_2-d_2)?$$

If $b_1=b_2=d_1=d_2=0$, then it becomes the rearrangement inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is  $a_1=3$, $a_2=2$, $b_1=0$, $b_2=1$, $c_1=3$, $c_2=4$, $d_1=0$, $d_2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be shown using the same method used to prove the rearrangement inequality. Each term is greater than $0$ so the following holds:

Let $\mu_1 = (c_1-d_1)$ and  $\mu_2 = (c_2-d_2)$. The RHS $(a_1-b_1)\mu_1+(a_2-b_2)\mu_2$ does not decrease when we swap $a_1$ with $a_2$ if $a_1 \geq a_2$ and $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2$. Similarly, it does not decrease if we swap $b_1$ with $b_2$ if $b_1 \geq b_2$ and $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2$. This is basically rearrangement inequality applied twice.

Repeat the argument with $\mu_1 = (a_1-b_1)$ and  $\mu_2 = (a_2-b_2)$ and the $c_i, b_i$. Finally, notice that the arrangement you end up with is given by your LHS above.

Comment: Dear @dmh, Sorry, but if $a_1\le a_2$, $\mu_i:=c_i-d_i$, $\mu_1\le \mu_2$, then $(a_1-b_1)\mu_1+(a_2-b_2)\mu_2\ge (a_2-b_1)\mu_1+(a_1-b_2)\mu_2$, which means that RHS decreases when we swap $a_1$ with $a_2$.

Comment: I had the sign wrong :)

Comment: Dear @dmh, Still, if $b_1\ge b_2$, $\mu_i:=c_i-d_i$, $\mu_1\le \mu_2$, then RHS decreases if we swap $b_1$ with $b_2$.

Comment: I should have been more explicit. In the case you mentioned we font swap the values of $b_i$. But if $b_2$ is larger, then we swap